# How can I fill a multidimensional array by indexes?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am trying to full a multidimensional array by it's index. When an index is completed, then go to the next, ...

I have to do it whithout arraylist.

My code:

```
for(i = 0; i < tridimensional.length; i++){
    for(j=0; j < tridimensional[i].length; j++){
            for(k=0; k < tridimensional[i][j].length; k++){
                tridimensional[i][j][k] = (int) (Math.random() * 10+1);
            }
        }
    }
```

To clarify the result:

```
INDEX:1
79  29  25  84  41  62  81  31  12  
63  13  87  71  4   46  21  20  47  
85  60  32  37  27  11  33  51  55

INDEX:N
50  82  72  15  74  80  5   17  43  
58  52  64  57  76  56  26  2   68  
39  54  77  48  70  73  8   86  34
```

I have a method to randomize numbers and doesn't repeat. I works for bidimensional array but I want to make it work in a tridimensional array for every matrix in tridimensional[i].

```
for(i = 0; i < tridimensional.length; i++){
        for(j=0; j < tridimensional[i].length; j++){
            for(k=0; k < tridimensional[i][j].length; k++){
                do {
                rand= (int) (Math.random() * 89+1);
                } while (exist(tridimensional, rand));
                tridimensional[i][j][k] = rand;
            }
        }
    }

public static boolean exist(int[][][] tridimensional, int n) {
    boolean exist = false;
    int i, j, k;

     for(i = 0; i < tridimensional.length; i++){

        for(j=0; j < tridimensional[i].length; j++){
            for(k=0; k < tridimensional[i][j].length; k++){
                   if(tridimensional[i][j][k]==n) {
                    exist = true;
                   }
            }
        }
    }


    return exist;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: This isn't clear.  What is the issue with the above code?

Comment: What happens? Is there an exception?

Comment: It's difficult for me to explain it, but I will try. Every tridimensional[i] has an individual bidimensional matrix and I need to fill it individually.

Comment: I think that was clear. But what is the unexpected behavior with your code?

Comment: I'm trying to explain it better with example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that Java doesn't really have multi-dimensional arrays; it has arrays of arrays. You need to create those subarrays:

```
// I assume here, you've already initialized `tridimensional`
for(i = 0; i < tridimensional.length; i++){
    tridimensional[i] = new int[/*...appropriate size here*/];        // <===
    for(j=0; j < tridimensional[i].length; j++){
        tridimensional[i][j] = new int[/*...appropriate size here*/]; // <===
        for(k=0; k < tridimensional[i][j].length; k++){
             tridimensional[i][j][k] = (int) (Math.random() * 10+1);
        }
    }
}
```